Apache Iceberg Partitioning
Can someone help me understand the difference between 'hour' and 'hours' partitioning? If I partition by HOUR(created_dt), will it also work if I filter using MONTH(created_dt) in the WHERE clause, I mean if scan will do by partition, cause Iceberg does not let me to create redundant partitions.
select count(*)  from bng.raw_game_actions where hours(played_at)=19;
returns nothing
select count(*)  from bng.raw_game_actions where hour(played_at)=19;
return what expected

In the PARTITIONED BY clause, hours() is the 'Old syntax' and it supported for compatibility. hour() or date_hour() is the new syntax. These are partition transformations.
See: https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/spark-ddl/#partitioned-by
In your SELECT statement hour() is a SQL function and not related to partition transformations. The SQL function will convert the timestamp into hour-of-day.
The hour() partition transformation will transform a timestamp into the number of hours since 1970-01-01.  It does not mean hour-of-day.
According to the description of Iceberg's hidden partitioning, if you partition by HOUR(ts) it can use that partition for other queries against the same timestamp field.
https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/partitioning/#icebergs-hidden-partitioning

Hi Greg , thanks for you answer ,I also want to clear one thing i have a table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bng.raw_game_actions (
origin   string, played_at   timestamp,
)
USING iceberg
PARTITIONED BY (hour(played_at),game_name)
if i want to run a query for example like this
select * from bng.raw_game_actions where date(played_at) = '2023-12-01';
It should scan hidden partition ? because i   did  test and it runs near 100 seconds , and then i have decided to replace field played_at which is timestamp and add it as date and then do  just partition by date  and it works near 5 seconds.

I mean i have added just partition by played_at and this column in another test  is as  date column
